# FOSUserBundle "Register" route redirects to "Login" route

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've just installed FOSUserBundle for Symfony2 using ORM with MySQL, but I haven't been able to make the registration page available for anonymous users.

If i go to

http://myapp.localhost/login

It shows the login form, however if I go to:

http://myapp.localhost/register

It redirects me back to the login form.

Here's the catch, if I login in the `login` screen, and then navigate to the `register` screen, then the registration form shows up.

Looking at the logs, this is what I get:

```
request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_registration_register" 
(parameters: "_controller":
 "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction",
   "path": "/register/",
   "permanent": "true",
   "scheme": "null",
   "httpPort": "80",
   "httpsPort": "443", "_route": "fos_user_registration_register") [] []

 request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_registration_register" 
 (parameters: "_controller": 
 "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction", 
 "_route": "fos_user_registration_register") [] []

  security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
  [2013-08-12 13:48:37] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
  [2013-08-12 13:48:37] security.DEBUG: Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated) by "/usr/share/www/etsytracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 73; redirecting to authentication entry point [] []
```

So it seems like I'm getting an anonymous token, but then Symfony says that I'm not fully authenticated and kicks me out to the login page.

Here's my security.yml file:

```
security:
acl:
   connection: default
encoders:
   FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout: true
        anonymous: true

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/register$,                roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/login$,                   roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/resetting$,               roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/,                         roles: 'ROLE_USER'  }
    - { path: ^/admin,                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

and my config.yml regarding FOSBundle:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: TestBundle\MyTestBundle\Entity\Users
```

Comment: Do you maybe have a sub request in you're layout to an restricted ressource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by m0c.

In my config.yml file I had that the `^/` path should only be accessed by authenticated users, and I only whitelisted the `^login$` path, not the `^/register$` path.

removing `^/` the roles for that path, solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another rule for secured area.

ex.:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/register$,  roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/login$,     roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/resetting$, roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/dashboard,  roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
    - { path: ^/.*,         roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { path: ^/admin,      roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```